# Can we approximate harmonic maps which are a.e. orientation-preserving with maps which preserve orientation globally?

Tags: sobolev-spaces, approximation-theory, jacobians, harmonic-functions, quasiconformal

Let $\mathbb{D}^n$ be the closed unit ball, and let $f:\mathbb{D}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be **harmonic**; More precisely, I assume that $f$ is real-analytic and harmonic on the interior $(\mathbb{D}^n)^o$ and smooth on the entire closed ball.

Suppose also that $n \ge 2$, and that $\det df >0$ a.e. on $\mathbb{D}^n$.

> Are there **harmonic** maps $\omega_n: \mathbb{D}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$, such that $\det d\omega_n >0$ **everywhere** on $\mathbb{D}^n$, and $\omega_n \to f$ in $W^{1,2}( \mathbb{D}^n,\mathbb{R}^n)$?